# SIM5320e HTTPS Stack, can't make successful GET request

Tags: http, get, gprs

I'm currently using a SIM5320e 3G development board with CoolTerm and a PL203 serial to USB connector. The aim is once I can make a successful HTTP/HTTPS GET request I can then incorporate it into a micro-controller project that will transmit data from a remote sensor to the internet vis EDGE/GPRS/3G.

However my issue is I have yet to make a successful GET request. I have searched the internet and this site and there is not a vast amount of info on this board, besides the data sheet, which is quite complex. I'm sure I'm missing a crucial step but can't see what it is.

Here is the (typical) terminal output alongside my comments

```
AT

OK // Module is working

AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","giffgaff.com" // Setting the APN I am using Giffgaff UK sim card, this is the APN

OK

AT+CSOCKSETPN=1 // Not sure what this step is, but seems to need to happen according to the application note

OK

AT+CIPMODE=0 // Same again

OK

AT+NETOPEN=,,1

Network opened

OK // Opens the network connection via GPRS
AT+IPADDR

+IPADDR: 10.146.130.153

OK // Appears to successfully get a network address
AT+CHTTPSSTART

OK // Starts the HTTPS/HTTP stack
AT+CHTTPSOPSE="www.iforce2d.net", 80,1

OK // Opens a connection to the host on port 80
AT+CHTTPSSEND=23    // Request to send 23 chars of data

>GET /test.php HTTP/1.1    // Web page exists, displays the time in UTC

OK  // Says OK
AT+CHTTPSSEND

OK  

+CHTTPSSEND: 0  // Says sent with no issue
AT+CHTTPSSEND?  // However, I query it

+CHTTPSSEND: 0  // However has sent no chars!

OK

+CHTTPSNOTIFY: PEER CLOSED
AT+CHTTPSRECV? //Query if anything has been received?

+CHTTPSRECV: LEN,0  // Hasn't received anything!

OK
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for looking.

Will.

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

With quite a lot of testing, managed to get `CHTTPSPOST` working.

My testing rig was a SIM7600E and there aren't many blogs or resources for this module out there yet

```
Serial2.println("AT+CHTTPSSTART"); xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(5, 0);   wdt_reset();                
Serial2.println("AT+CHTTPSOPSE=\"test.com/db\",443,2"); xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(5, 0);   wdt_reset();          
Serial.print  (" -Server conn "); Serial.println(xcode);  delay(100);
SIM_receiveSerial(1, 0);
SIM_receiveSerial(1, 0);
Serial2.println("AT+CHTTPSSEND=147");  
xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(1, 0);   wdt_reset();          Serial.print  (" -Server conn "); Serial.println(xcode);  

Serial.println("IN METHOD");

Serial2.print("POST https://test/com/db HTTP/1.1"); Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);  Serial.println(" -Post ");    
Serial2.print("Host: test.com");                                             Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);  Serial.println(" -host ");  
Serial2.print("Accept:*/*");                                                     Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);
Serial2.print("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);   Serial.println(" -Content-Type: ");                                            
Serial.println(" -Cache-Control: ");                                     
Serial.println(" -Accept-Charset: ");                                              
Serial.println(" -Pragma: ");    
Serial2.print("Content-Length:10");                                               
Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);  Serial.println(" -Content-Length: ");    
Serial2.print("");                                                                Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);   Serial.println(" -NL "); 
Serial2.print("&param=11");                                      Serial.println(" -api_token "); 
Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);
Serial2.write(13); Serial2.write(10);  
Serial2.write(0x1a);                                                                  Serial.println(" -CTRL+Z ");


xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
Serial2.println("AT+CHTTPSRECV?");  xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);   wdt_reset();          Serial.print  (" -Server conn "); Serial.println(xcode);   

xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);
Serial2.println("AT+CHTTPSSTATE");  xcode=SIM_receiveSerial(2, 0);   wdt_reset();          
Serial.print  (" -Server conn "); Serial.println(xcode);
```

You can receive the feedback by using `AT+CHTTPRECV`

`SIM_receiveSerial` is a function that waits for a reply from the sim module

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be useful. I used TeraTerm to send these commands to my `SIM5320E`. So I used `<Ctrl M>` and `<Ctrl J>` instead of `'<CR> <LF> OR /n/r'` characters.

**Network setup**

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","<your APN>","0.0.0.0"
AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","<your APN>"
AT+CSOCKSETPN=1
```

**Start HTTP service**
You can stop and start service if it's not responding properly.

```
AT+CHTTPSSTART
AT+CHTTPACT="www.iforce2d.net",80
```

**HTTP GET request**

```
GET /test.php HTTP/1.1  <-- don't hit enter, instead hit the below 2 keys
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
Host: www.iforce2d.net  <-- don't hit enter, instead hit the below 2 keys
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
Connection: close  <-- don't hit enter, instead hit the below 4 keys. This is useful when connecting to REST APIs to download the the respective result only.
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
<Ctrl M>
<Ctrl J>
```

To end the command and to receive results:

```
<Ctrl Z>
```

You will receive a lot of data here.

**Stop HTTP service**

```
AT+CHTTPSCLSE
AT+CHTTPSSTOP
```

You will get the contents of the website. Probably it should contain the data you need (I didn't test the content. May be you will need to tweek the result a bit.)