# Can NOT launch a HTTP operation using SIM5320E

Tags: arduino, at-command

I want to send/receive data to/from website by using SIM5320E.
Connection between my PC and module SIM5320E is look good because the AT command responses OK. But the command to launch a HTTP operation gets ERROR.
It seems that my SIM5320E is NOT connected to 3G network. The GPRS is no longer available in Japan (DOCOMO) now.

How to active SIM4320E connect to 3G ?

This is my current result.

```
AT
OK

AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"NTT DOCOMO",2
OK

AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","line.me"
OK

AT+CSOCKSETPN=1
OK

AT+CSOCKAUTH=1,3,"line","line@line"
OK

AT+CHTTPACT=?
+CHTTPACT: "ADDRESS",(1-65535)
OK

// I got error from here

AT+CPING="google.com",1
OK
+CPING: 3,0,0,0,0,0,0

AT+CHTTPACT="google.com",80
+CHTTPACT: 237
ERROR

AT+CHTTPACT="www.google.com",80  
+CHTTPACT: 237
ERROR

AT+CHTTPACT="stackoverflow.com",80
+CHTTPACT: 237
ERROR
```

Update 1: Also tried this

```
AT+CMEE=2
OK

AT+CHTTPSSTART
ERROR

AT+CHTTPSSTART\r\nAT+CHTTPSOPSE="pruebas.libelium.com",80,1\r\nAT+CHTTPSSEND=88\r\n"GET / HTTP/1.1"\r\nHost: pruebas.libelium.com\r\nContent-Length: 0" 
ERROR
```

Update 2: Also tried

```
AT+CNMP?
+CNMP: 2
OK

AT+CNAOP? 
+CNAOP: 2
OK

AT+CPSI?
+CPSI: WCDMA,Online,440-10,0x01C6,72728730,WCDMA IMT 2000,331,10736,0,4.5,70,31,45,500
OK

AT+CHTPSERV="ADD","www.google.com",80,1
OK

AT+CHTPUPDATE
OK
+CHTPUPDATE: 4  // Network error
```

Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: try to get more specific error messages than `ERROR` by enabling CMEE: `AT+CMEE=2`. See chapter 9 in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) for more details.

Comment: AT+CMEE?
+CMEE: 2

OK
.   It has already be set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download web site data using SIM5320E module. Haven't used SIM4320E though but should be quite similar.

Follow the exact steps in [SIM5320e HTTPS Stack, can't make successful GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129232/3073378) which worked for me.

*From what you have provided:*
You have selected the correct module for DOCOMO band (2100Mhz) according to [Cellular Bands in Japan](http://eng.blogfromamerica.com/archives/31). Since `AT+CPSI?` and `AT+COPS?` shows it's online with WCDMA so may assume it's connected to network. You can use `AT+CREG?` and `AT+CGREG?` to see whether your voice and data connections are registered with the network (It must be registered with the network)

If it's not connected to the network. Try `AT+COPS=2` to force it to select a network.

AT+CHTTPSSTART can fail, if the HTTPS service has already been started. So you can use following commands to restart it.

```
AT+CHTTPSCLSE
AT+CHTTPSSTOP
AT+CHTTPSTART
```

If you still face problems, try using this [Tutorial by SimComm](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/tutorial-for-simcom-m2m-modules/). It doesn't contain the 3G connectivity stuff. But you can make sure your module works fine with your network. Once it's ensured, try following the steps mentioned above.
All the best!